# fedora halt - not sure why

Tags: fedora, ibm, physical-environment

Got a brand new server (IBM x3500) yesterday, installed Fedora 12 on it and thought we'd run some code to see how it performs.

After around 7 hours of running, the system seems to have halted.

The symptoms were -
The fans were still on ie system sounded like it was running
The monitor, mouse and keyboard did not receive power and were disabled.
The cd tray still opened/closed.
The link light was flashing.

My first thought was temperature but cant find any info/logs regarding temperature.

After rebooting I can't seem to find any log file that looks like a system log.

where would you look for causes?

**EDIT: more info**

just happened again, under similar circumstances.

3.5 hours into a hefty procedure: pop!

I did have a "top" going at the time:

```
top - 15:26:41 up  4:26,  4 users,  load average: 2.67, 2.38, 2.37
Tasks: 246 total,   3 running, 243 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 48.2%us,  1.5%sy,  0.0%ni, 48.4%id,  1.1%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.9%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   8252304k total,  8192272k used,    60032k free,    23592k buffers
Swap: 10354680k total,   146024k used, 10208656k free,  6350148k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 3934 pstanton  20   0 1881m 322m 3900 S 99.5  4.0 141:57.88 java
 3894 pstanton  20   0 1881m 336m 3896 S 95.2  4.2 169:54.01 java
 3914 pstanton  20   0 1881m 315m 3936 S 84.6  3.9 151:52.13 java
 3875 pstanton  20   0 1881m 271m 3948 S 73.3  3.4 179:25.13 java
 3893 pstanton  20   0  317m 208m 206m S 31.2  2.6  33:22.98 postgres
 3932 pstanton  20   0  317m 208m 206m S 16.9  2.6  63:02.05 postgres
 3912 pstanton  20   0  317m 208m 206m R  6.6  2.6  43:27.91 postgres
 4292 pstanton  20   0  325m  13m 4032 S  1.3  0.2   0:00.37 postgres
 4288 pstanton  20   0  325m  22m  12m S  0.7  0.3   0:03.45 postgres
   59 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S  0.3  0.0   0:03.81 ata/1
  358 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S  0.3  0.0   0:04.54 kjournald2
 1585 root      20   0  165m 7204 2168 S  0.3  0.1   1:37.06 Xorg
 2002 root      20   0 42192  380  308 S  0.3  0.0   0:04.03 devkit-disks-da
 3968 pstanton  20   0  288m 7280 3760 S  0.3  0.1   0:02.08 gnome-terminal
 4291 pstanton  20   0  325m  13m 4076 S  0.3  0.2   0:01.41 postgres
 4337 pstanton  20   0 15036 1244  848 R  0.3  0.0   0:00.09 top
    1 root      20   0  4056  596  492 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.91 init
```

I can see that I am using swap memory which isn't good, but that shouldn't halt the server?

Also, this time i had a keyboard, mouse and monitor plugged in already and there is power to the keyboard and mouse but the monitor is blank (not even a cursor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was likely due to bad binaries for fedora. we've since installed 2 other OS's without problems. thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to get into the BMC to get the error logs for the hardware, or you need to run IBM Director.
Also, if you have an RSA card in the server, you can hit the web page of the RSA card and it will show you the last hardware errors detected.

Answer (score 0):

The System Error Log should tell you what's going on; I'd be inclined to just lodge a warranty fault and let IBM sort it out, though -- although you'll probably need to reproduce the problem on a supported OS before they'll take you seriously.

Comment: where do i find the system error log?

Comment: Try ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/systems/support/system_x/44r5218.pdf or Google.